# Subway lines in KML with different colors on one track?

Tags: google-maps, kml

My first KML project was an animated map of the Washington DC Metro system (see [Animating Metro with KML and Google Earth](http://www.mvjantzen.com/blog/?p=1207)). Unfortunately, where Metro lines share the same track, only one color prevails. The real map shows a wider line with both colors side by side.

Is there a way to draw a line in KML (Google Earth) with two side-by-side colors? I've seen a way to have a different color on the edges of the line, but that's different.

I could cheat by changing the coordinates of each station, but aside from computational difficulties, I'd have to continuously changes to positions every time the user zooms, to prevent a gap between colors (or an overlap).

Other subway systems show more than two colors running alongside each other, so an option to show multiple colors would be nice. And this is not really a gradient, as the colors don't fade together; they should be distinct, assuming the pixel width is wide enough.

This is probably a feature request, though surely someone else has run across this problem before Google Earth v6? Would love to be able to do this, or find a good workaround in the interim.

Michael
http://www.mvjantzen.com/blog/

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is no, although you could probably create a custom MVC object that renders the line for you as desired (i.e. you would not need to alter the Kml)

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/articles/mvcfun.html

That said, your cheat method could work too - and I would disagree that

> "...I'd have to continuously changes to positions every time the user
>   zooms, to prevent a gap between colors"

You can set the `<gx:physicalWidth>` property which allows you to set the width of a LineString to be in meters, rather than pixels.

https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#gxphysicalwidth

In the case of your track example, this means you can set the width of the track to match the underlying imagery no matter what altitude the end user views it from.